# InvalidDataContractException in switching to dormant state

Tags: telerik, windows-phone-8

I am using telerik pan and zoom image control in my application.My issue is once I put the page containing the panandzoom image control in dormat state and retrieves back the application is crashed stating the following,

A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException' occurred in System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll

This issue is not reproduced if I have removed the pan and zoom image control from my page, do you have any fixed solution for this, could anyone suggest a solution as soon as possible for this,

Regards,
 Mawy Peter

Comment: Any network calls your app does will be cancelled once the app goes dormant. Are you doing any network calls in your app at this point?

Comment: What version of the controls? Is it just an empty control you're adding to the page? Can you show/share a way to reproduce this? Are you doing anything with the control (or the data you're binding to it) when you navigate to and/or from the page?

Comment: Any code you can provide will help us diagnose your problem. The official help documentation can be found here: http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-phone/panandzoomimage-overview.html